# Has anyone succeeded with running the Renderscript demos on a device?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, renderscript

I keep getting this error message with every single Renderscript demo:

```
05-21 17:49:01.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6704): android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm only loading the demo projects in eclipse, compile and run them. This works well with every other Android demo, are these renderscript-demos different in some manner (apart from not working)?

I'm trying to get these working on a Galaxy 10.1 currently.

Edit: To clear things up, this problem has been solved. It was caused by a bug in the initial release of the SDK tools that contained Renderscript support. Google has fixed the issue since then.

Comment: The only thing really different is that the "glue" classes to connect the RenderScript (C99 side) and Java need to be generated.  This should happen for you automatically, but it looks like that's not happening.  I'd try doing a project clean and also, if you're running the latest ADT, you'll need to replace /platforms/android-[11|12|13]/renderscript with the version located at /platforms/android-14/renderscript

Answer (score 0):

Yes , they work. Usually i get compile time errors due to "int root()" function. you need to remove any arguments if present in the root method of the rs file.